# 0,1+0,2 === 0,3 - FALSE

Tags: javascript, coma-flotante, float

```
0.1 + 0.2 == 0.3
-> false

0.1 + 0.2
-> 0.30000000000000004
```

Como se puede resolver para que 0,1+0,2 de como  resultado 0,3?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mete el resultado en una variable y hazle ".toFixed(2)" para que limite los decimales a 2.

```
var a = 0.1;
var b = 0.2;
var c = a.toFixed(2) + b.toFixed(2);
-> true
```